# Magento2 Addtocart success msg disappear

Tags: message, magento2.4

After clicked the add to cart button success message disappear while detail page and list page.

I have used some code changes for messages.js

$.cookieStorage.setConf({path: '/', expires: -1}).set('mage-messages', null);

That's also not working.

Any one give suggestion magento2.4 success message flashout immediately.

I want success msg load properly after addtocart.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Magento 2.4.5 and I had issue with add to cart success messages on PDP and PLP, The success message was disappearing too quickly.

I found a solution, May be it helps someone in same boat.

Please modify as per your requirements.

working solution for me is

```
Overwrite Magento_Customer/js/customer-data.js
```

modify function `onAjaxComplete`

if sections have only `["messages"] then use settimeout`

I replaced function with

```
onAjaxComplete: function (jsonResponse, settings) {
            var sections,
                redirects;

            if (settings.type.match(/post|put|delete/i)) {
                sections = sectionConfig.getAffectedSections(settings.url);
                if(JSON.stringify(sections) !=='["messages"]') {
                    if (sections && sections.length) {
                        this.invalidate(sections);
                        redirects = ['redirect', 'backUrl'];
    
                        if (_.isObject(jsonResponse) && !_.isEmpty(_.pick(jsonResponse, redirects))) { //eslint-disable-line
                            return;
                        }
                        this.reload(sections, true);
                    }
                } else {
                    setTimeout(function() { 
                        sections = $.parseJSON('["messages"]');
                        customerData.reload(sections, true);
                    }, 5000);
                }
            }
        },
```